# Left/Right joins not returning nulls as expected

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB-10.2.6.

Currently schema as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `daily_report` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `daily_report_user_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` 
  (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `shall_create_every_day` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
  `datefield` date
)
```

Rules:

1. A user with `shall_create_every_day` set to `1` shall create a `daily_report` every day.
2. I have a calendar table `calendar`, which consists of every date from `2000-01-01` until `2020-12-31` (since generate_series is not available in MySQL/MariaDB)

I have tried the following query:

```
select daily_report.id, daily_report.date, user.id, calendar.datefield
from calendar
left join daily_report on daily_report.date=calendar.datefield
right join user on daily_report.user_id=user.id and user.shall_create_every_day=1
where calendar.datefield='2017-08-02'
```

I was trying for a daterange, but for testing purposes, I have limited the `where` statement to one day only.

It shall return all of the users, with `shall_create_every_day`, that have not created any `daily_report` at '2017-08-12'. But I am only getting the combination of created report on that day.

Is there anything that I misunderstood about left/right joins returning nulls for not-matched rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never combine left and right joins; this is just confusing. (Well, most of us never use right joins at all, as they are harder to read then left joins.)

Your query does this:

1. Get all calendar records.
2. Join daily_report records if available, else create an empty dummy record to join.
3. Get all user records with shall_create_every_day = 1.
4. Join the first data set to the users if available, else create an empty dummy record to join to the user.
5. Dismiss all outer-joined records created in (4), by applying a where clause.

So first of all you should ask yourself: do I need an outer join at all? Concerning users and calendar you don't. Actually all you want from the calendar is to check whether an entry for '2017-08-02' exists. And as to the users table: this is mere criteria, too; you want all reports for certain users and a certain date.

So select from the reports table and have the criteria where it belongs: in your `WHERE` clause.

```
select id, date, user_id
from daily_report 
where user_id in (select id from user where shall_create_every_day = 1)
and date = (select datefield from calendar where datefield = '20170802');
```

To show dates and users with their reports including missing reports, you'd cross join calendar and users and left join the reports:

```
select r.id, c.datefield, u.id as user_id
from (select id from user where shall_create_every_day = 1) u
cross join (select datefield from calendar where datefield = '20170802') c
left join daily_report r on r.user_id = u.id and r.date = c.datefield;
```

Comment: I just figured out that using both left and right joins at the same time is a very bad idea. Just found out a viable solution with cross join and left join, and will post an answer later.

Comment: But why join at all? As you see, you don't want a joined result; you only want data from the reports table. Don't join.

Comment: Or do you want to show missing reports for dates and users, too? Then yes, cross join calendar and users and left join the reports.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to show missing reports for dates/users.

Comment: I've added the query, so you can compare it with yours.

Comment: Actually your query is as same as mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Generate series is available in MariaDB.  See [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/sequence-storage-engine/) .  It is something like

```
SELECT '2000-01-01' + INTERVAL seq
    FROM seq_0_241
```

You can `JOIN` to such, without actually materializing a table.

Please don't mix `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.  It is either the cause of the problem, or my head is too busy spinning to understand it.  Keep in mind that it might be interpreted as

```
FROM a LEFT JOIN (b RIGHT JOIN c)
```

which is probably not what you wanted.  In any case, parentheses are permitted (and encouraged when mixing `LEFT` and `RIGHT`).

Answer (score 0):

You phrased your query in a somewhat convoluted way.  I would phrase this by left joining the `user` table to a second table containing entries for reports by each user, on each day.  The hallmark of a user who did not write would then be that a given user record does not match to anything in this second table.

```
select
    u.id
from user u
left join
(
    select
        c.datefield,
        dr.me_id
    from calendar c
    left join daily_report dr
        on dr.date = c.datefield
    where c.datefield = '2017-08-02'
 ) cal
    on cal.me_id = u.id and
       u.shall_create_every_day = 1
where
    cal.me_id is null;
```

Comment: Yes. This is what I am trying to query for, but the query you provided still doesn't return any rows. Even with the `daily_report.me_id is null` removed, all it show is rows without null in any fields.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done this way.

```
SELECT * 
FROM daily_report 
RIGHT JOIN (calendar c,user u) ON user_id=u.id AND date=c.datefield 
WHERE c.datefield='2017-08-02' AND u.shall_create_every_day=1
```

P.S. Probably there is an error in the table structure. `daily_report.user_id` should be `int` instead of `varchar`.